# How can I properly transition between yolov3 and yolov4 for opencv?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, yolo

In my old project, I used a yolov3 model and trained it, and the used cv2.readNetFromDarknet(...), cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(...), and net.forward(...) in order to run my inference and it worked fine. I trained my yolov4 model and assumed that I only had to change the configuration and weights file in my project in order for the inference to work but instead I get no detected bounding boxes. Is there supposed to be a change other than the weights and configs? Thank you.

edit:

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(PATHS["model_config"], PATHS["model_weights"])
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layer_names = [ layer_names[index[0] - 1] for index in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers() ]

#during inference
def method(frame):
   blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1 / 255.0, (MAGIC_NUMBER_1, 
   MAGIC_NUMBER_1), swapRB=True, crop=False)
   net.setInput(blob)
   layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layer_names)

   boxes = []
   confidences = []
   classIDs = []

   for output in layerOutputs:
          for detection in output:
               scores = detection[5:]
               classID = np.argmax(scores)
               confidence = scores[classID]
            
               if confidence > .5: # NEVER PASSES, CONFIDENCE IS ALWAYS 0 WHEN PRINTED OUT
                
                   box = detection[0:4] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
                   (centerX, centerY, width, height) = box.astype("int")

                   x = int(centerX - (width / 2))
                   y = int(centerY - (height / 2))

                   boxes.append([x, y, int(width), int(height)])
    
                   confidences.append(float(confidence))
                   classIDs.append(classID)

   return boxes, confidences, classIDs
```

Comment: maybe confidence threshold, if your training is confused (e.g. because of inappropriate training data). If you share your code we can check for other problems.

Comment: Added code by editing post